# I am getting "Expected identifier but got '(' receive() external payable" this error when I write the code below

Tags: solidity

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 < 0.9.0;

contract project{
    address public manager;
    address[] public perticipants;
    constructor(){
        manager = msg.sender;
    }
    receive() external payable{
        perticipants.push(msg.sender);
        
    }
    function balance() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your solidity version. The `receive() external payable` function was added in Solidity version 0.6.0. So, you need to upgrade your solidity version to something like `>=0.6.0 < 0.9.0` or `^0.8.0`:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 < 0.9.0;

contract project{
    address public manager;
    address[] public perticipants;
    constructor() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }
    receive() external payable{
        perticipants.push(msg.sender);
        
    }
    function balance() public view returns(uint){
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

For more details, check this article: https://betterprogramming.pub/solidity-0-6-x-features-fallback-and-receive-functions-69895e3ffe

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler range is too large for that code. I get your error when I run a Solidity compiler of version 0.5.0, e.g.

You say: "You can run this with Solidity 0.5 or 0.8".

But that code is very different in those two Solidity versions.

Therefore, you need to increase your compiler. Are you running this in Remix? If so, change the compiler version to 0.8.16, e.g. and it should be fine.

I would suggest changing this:

`pragma solidity >=0.5.0 < 0.9.0;`

To, e.g.:

`pragma solidity >=0.7.0 < 0.9.0;`

And for production systems, it's recommended to fix the compiler version, so something like this:

`pragma solidity 0.8.16;`